# JavaScript libraries for touch screen devices

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, mobile, webkit

I know there are a number of frameworks to help make web applications on Mobile Safari/Webkit look and behave like native applications (eg, jQTouch), but are there any more light-weight libraries that help out at a slightly lower-level?

eg, I might want to add some animations on certain touch events to reproduce an iPhone style swipe.

I don't want to create an iPhone web application as such, just enhance an existing site with a few special touch events.

It's not so difficult to create this stuff by directly using the touch events that the device provides, but some of the iPhone animation styles are quite complex to reproduce. eg, the bounce when you get to the end of a scroll bar, etc... Just wondering if anyone has done the work and wrapped it up into an open source library.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question completely, but since you mentioned bounce scrolling specifically, [TouchScroll](http://uxebu.com/blog/2010/04/27/touchscroll-a-scrolling-layer-for-webkit-mobile/) was just released on Tuesday.

Comment: Yeah, just came across this after posting, and it looks like it's not a million miles from being useful. Except that it's focussed just around scrolling (and as far as I can see, only vertically). It might be a useful starting point though. I think the real problem I have is that I can't quite define what it is I'm after, even in my own head. I'll go away and think about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing, JavaScript frameworks free from IE stuff..

So far

**XUI**
http://code.google.com/p/xui-js/

**SLY**
http://github.com/digitarald/sly

**Coming Soon**
jQuery for touch devices (not jqtouch) http://jquerymobile.com/2010/08/announcing-the-jquery-mobile-project/

Answer (score 0):

http://zeptojs.com/ is all you want.

It's jQuery trimmed for webkit mobile. Excellent library with (brand new) great documentation. Handles ajax, dom selection, touch events. Does not have UI components.

Very lightweight.